# Rails: Grouping Partials Based on an Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, calendar, partial, partials

I've got an application that uses a calendar, and I'd like to provide a calendar summary on login.  The summary should be formatted so it shows events for Today, Tomorrow, and This Week, like this:

> Events For:
>
> Today
>
> - Event 1
>
> Tomorrow
>
> - Event 2
> - Event 3
> - Event 4
>
> This Week
>
> - Event 5
> - Event 6
> - Event 7
> - Event 8

How do I render the partials so that they are grouped together in the right way, based on their date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one could add a model method for_dates(start_date,end_date) which would contain:
`where([:date_column >= ? and :date_column <= ?, start_date, end_date])`

Then use:

`Model.for_dates(Date.today, Date.today)`

`Model.for_dates(Date.today+1, Date.today+1)`

Default 'week' is Sunday to Monday.  Add an offset if you wish different days, e.g.

Monday to Friday is

`Model.for_dates(Date.today.beginning_of_week+1, Date.today.end_of_week+1)`

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your model is called `Event` and it has a `date` attribute, and your collection of these is called `@events`, here's one idea: Put this in your view...

```
<ul>
<%= render @events, locals: { events: @events } %>
</ul>
```

...then you would have a partial called `_event.html.erb` that looks like this:

```
<%  last_event = event_counter == 0 ? nil : events[event_counter - 1]
    next_event = events[event_counter + 1]
%>
<%  if last_event && last_event.date != event.date
    # add a new date header and start a new nested list of events
%>
  <li><h3><%= event.date %></h3>
    <ul>
<% end %>

      <li><%= link_to event %></li>

<%  if next_event && next_event.date != event.date
    # end the nested list and make way for the next date header and set of events
%>
    </ul>
  </li>
<%  end %>
```

What's happing is in the `render` call we're passing in the whole `@events` collection as a local called `events`. Then inside the partial we use the automatically-generated `event_counter` method to look up the previous (`events[event_counter - 1]`) and next (`events[event_counter + 1]`) events in the collection. Then if the date of the current `event` is different from the date of `last_event` (meaning it's the first one for that date) we start a new set with a new date heading, and if the date of `event` is different from the date of `next_event` (i.e. it's the last one for that date) we end the set.

It's a little ugly, and there are more elegant ways to do it for sure, but it gets the job done.